# How to load silverlight player into browser to play video using PHP

Tags: php, silverlight, video, youtube, video-streaming

I am trying to build a web which broadcast video. For that  I chose Silverlight as player. But I dont know how to load the silverlight player. I searched in google but nothing helps me. Please give me suggestions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's all client-side - it is server-agnostic. It "just works".

Answer (score 1):

Can be as easy as

```
<?php
// some code here
?>
<object id="SilverlightMediaPlayer"
  type="application/x-silverlight-2"
  data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," autoupdate="true"
  style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"
>
  <param name="MinRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0"/>
  <param name="Source" value="<?php echo $url_videodata; ?>" />
  <param name="windowless" value="true" />
</object>
```

PHP itself doesn't care (much) about what you print/output to the client. You "just" have to send something that the *client* will parse and interpret the way you want it.

Comment: No, php really, really doesn't care about silverlight at all. It makes no difference to php whether you send 'Mary had a little lamb' or '<object type="application/x-silverlight-2" .... </object>'